# Obtener tamaño original de la imagen que contiene una sub vista Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Como puedo obtener el tamaño original de la imagen de una sub vista que no sea a través de su nombre, con sub vista me refiero a UIImageview, UIButton, UILabel ect.

Comment: la imagen te refieres a una `UIImage`? Puedes usar su propiedad size...

Comment: a si es compañero

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
NSData *dataImagen = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imagenUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImagen];
NSLog(@"image altura: %f",image.size.height);
NSLog(@"image anchura: %f",image.size.width);
```